# Diameter of a circle from offset radius

Tags: geometry

I have a question regarding the geometric properties of a circle.

For any circle, when taking the radius from the center of the circle, the radius will be constant throughout the whole circle.

However, my given issue is occurs when the radius is not taken at the center of the circle. Assuming that the radius of the circle is offset such that the radius is taken from a point below the circle instead. Assuming that the radius of the circle is now taken at every 45 degree interval, resulting in 8 different radiuses.

Using these 8 given radiuses, would it be possible to deduce the circumference of the circle?

Thanks for reading through, and appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: The answer will almost certainly turn out to be yes. But one needs to know what you mean by "radius is taken from a point below the circle."

Comment: Are your "radii" measured from the fixed external point to points on the circle which are spaced along the circle at 45-degree increments, with these angles being measured normally from the center with respect to a ray emanating horizontally to the right from the center of the circle?

Comment: And is the location of the fixed external point known?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! For a usual circle, the radius is taken at its center. However, the  issue I am facing is due to the fact that the 8 radius that is given is not taken at the center of the circle, but instead at some other arbitary point within the circle.

Comment: OK, so from inside the circle (the initial post said below the circle). What is radius from a point $P$? The distance to the nearest point $N_P$ on the circle? And now do we rotate the line $PN_P$? If so, one more "radius" should be enough.

Comment: So, the distances (let's not say the "radius" - too confusing) are measured from a point $(a,b)$ inside the circle.  Is $(a,b)$ given, or do you have to find it?

Comment: @André Nicolas
Could you refer to the 2nd diagram on the 1st answer posted below? Thanks!

Comment: @David Hmmmm perhaps you could take the point to be at the coordinates (0,0)?

Comment: So you want your points equally spaced around the circle, meaning the angles are not necessarily $45^\circ$, which they are in the first diagram. In any case, there is plenty enough information to get the radius. Just unpleasant algebra, much simpler if angles are equal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas 
Thanks for your reply! I will try out the solutions given below and see if they work out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the distances from the point **within** the circle are in fact arranged every 45º *around that point*, there should be three pairs of measurements with identical values within each pair, owing to the symmetry of the circle.  Two measurements will not be paired -- the shortest and longest among them.  These would be 180º apart, so they fall on a diameter of the circle: the radius of the circle is half the sum of those lengths.  The center is midway between the location of those endpoints.  (Not much  of this would be true in general if the curve *weren't* a circle.)

Is this the situation you're asking about?

[image]

Or do you mean the 8 points are spaced equally around the circumference?

[image]

This is a bit inelegant, but here's something you can try.  If you know the relative positions of the eight points around the circle, take any three that are 45º apart and make them "cardinal points" $ \ (R, \ 0) \ , \ ( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R, \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R) \  $ and  $ \ (0, \ R) \ $ .  Let the interior point of the circle be $ \ (X,Y) \ $ .  If we call the known measurements from $ \ (X, \ Y) \ $ to each of these points $ \ s_1 \ , \ s_2 \  $ and $ \ s_3 \ $ , then we can write

$$ (X \ - \ R)^2 \ + \ Y^2 \ = \ s_1^2 \ \ , \quad \mathbf{[1]} $$

$$ (X \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R)^2 \ + \ (Y \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R)^2 \ = \ s_2^2 \ \ , \quad \mathbf{[2]} $$

$$ \ \ X^2 \ + \ (Y \ - \ R)^2 \ = \ s_3^2 \ \ . \quad \mathbf{[3]} $$

We can then solve these equations simultaneously for the radius of the circle and the coordinates of the unspecified point relative to the  center of the circle. (I initially tried this using the quadrant points, but too many terms cancel out.)

**EDIT (6/19) --**

I should mention that it is not easy to simply "make up a problem" for this method.  While it is the case that three non-collinear points define a circle, and choosing three such points at random will lead to a solution circle, it is not simple to pick three lengths and expect to obtain a "radiant point" and a radius for the circle in this "inverse problem".

I found that I had to draw a circle and take measurements in order to test this approach (just using randomly-selected length measurements can lead to a non-solution with inconsistent results).  For the measurements $ \ s_1 \ = \ 3.5 \ , \ s_2 \ = \ 3.7 \ , \ s_3 \ = \ 7.55 \ , \ $ we can solve the system of equations **1 - 3** above as:

$$ (X \ - \ R)^2 \ + \ Y^2 \ = \ 3.5^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ X^2 \ + \ Y^2 \ + \ R^2 \ = \ 3.5^2 \ + \ 2RX \quad \mathbf{[A]} \ , $$

$$  X^2 \ + \ (Y \ - \ R)^2 \ = \ 7.55^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ X^2 \ + \ Y^2 \ + \ R^2 \ = \ 7.55^2 \ + \ 2RY  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 2RX \ - \ 2RY \ = \ 7.55^2 \ - \ 3.5^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ RX \ - \ RY \ \approx \ 22.376 \ \ ; $$

$$ (X \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R)^2 \ + \ (Y \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}R)^2 \ = \ 3.7^2 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ X^2 \ + \ Y^2 \ + \ R^2 \ = \ 3.7^2 \ + \ \sqrt{2} \ RX \ + \ \sqrt{2} \ RY $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 3.5^2 \ + \ 2RX \ \approx \ 3.7^2 \ + \ \sqrt{2} \ RX \ + \ \sqrt{2} \  (RX \ - \ 22.376) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ RX \ \approx \ 36.478 \ \ , \ \ RY \ \approx \ 14.102 \ \ . $$

We can now insert these results into, say, equation $ \ \mathbf{A} \ $ to obtain

$$ \left( \frac{36.478}{R} \right)^2 \ + \ \left( \frac{14.102}{R} \right)^2 \ + \ R^2 \ = \ 3.5^2 \ + \ 2 \ \cdot \ 36.478  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1529.52}{R^2} \ + \ R^2 \ \approx \ 85.206 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ R^4 \ - \ 85.206 \ R^2 \ + \ 1529.52 \ = \ 0 \ \ .  $$

The polynomial function in this equation has even symmetry, so its four (real) solutions are $ \ \approx \ \pm 5.070 \ , \ \approx \ \pm 7.714 \ $ .  Since the values are supposed to represent the radius of a circle, we discard the negative solutions and may now conclude

$$ R \ \approx \ 5.070 \ \ , \ \ (X, \ Y) \ \approx \ ( \ 7.195, \ 2.781 \ ) \ \ , $$

$$ R \ \approx \ 7.714 \ \ , \ \ (X, \ Y) \ \approx \ ( \ 4.729, \ 1.828 \ ) \ \ . $$

There are *two* solutions:  upon graphing them, we see that the smaller circle [shown in red below] provides the result for which the "radiant point" is *external* to the circle, while the larger circle [in blue] has the *internal* radiant point.

[image]

A striking feature of these paired circles is that the radiant point for the segments extending to the points on the smaller circle appears to lie on the larger circle, and *vice versa*.  Having worked on a couple other examples, this does not seem to be a coincidence.  I suspect there is a theorem underlying this, but I haven't taken time to prove it yet (it is likely a known result in circle geometry, though I'm not familiar with it...).

One may well modify the above calculations appropriately to work with other choices among the eight points.

[Now I feel a bit better about receiving the up-votes and "checkmark".]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attempt to help me answer my question!
Your 2nd solution is really helpful! I will try it out and perhaps let you know the outcome again. 
However, may I clarify as to how you managed to derive and find the different coordinates on the circle as seen in your second diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm entirely satisfied with this second part yet, since the three equations turn out to be linearly dependent.  I may be revising this later, though something along this line should work.  As for the points on the circle, I am placing the (unknown) center of the circle of (unknown) radius $ \ R \ $  at the origin, so the points at the quarters are as marked.  The point at 45º is then $ \ (R \cos \ 45º, \ R \sin \ 45º ) \ = \ (R / \sqrt{2} , \ R / \sqrt{2}) \ $ .

Comment: Okay, thanks! However, why is there 0 present within some of the points? Also, if the radius is different, how come the same variable R is used to represent different distances?

Comment: The distances from the point $ \ (X,Y) \ $ to the points on the circle are _not_ radii; a radius is always taken from the center of the circle.  The point $ \ (R, \ 0) \ $ is on a radius pointing right from the center of the circle, so it is $ \ R \ $ units to the right and zero units above the center; the point $ \ (0, \ R) \ $ is on a radius pointing "upward" from the center, so it is zero units to the right and $ \ R \ $ units above the center; and so on for the other quadrant points marked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I now understand your approach! I will attempt these methods. Would it be fine if i approach you later if I have any further questions regarding this question?

Comment: @AgentBlack I have a worked example for you.  Yes, you are welcome to contact me if you have any other questions.